# Want to send request in sync in node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose, synchronization

I have a scenario that I want to fetch data from collection and insert into an array and then return that array.

```
router.route('/user/:_id/host/:_id/joineeList').get(function(req, res) {
    var finalList = [];
    Host.findOne({
        _id : req.params._id,
    }, function(err, host) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            var count = host.joinees.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                console.log(host.joinees[i].userid);
                var ID = host.joinees[i].userid;
                var CODE = host.joinees[i].status_code;
                User.findOne({
                    _id : host.joinees[i].userid
                }, function(err1, user) {
                    if (err1) {
                        console.log(err1);
                    } else {
                        finalList.push({
                            "userId" : ID,
                            "name" : user.name,
                            "profilepic" : user.profilepic,
                            "status" : CODE
                        });
                        console.log(finalList);
                        // finalList[i].add = ("userId",ID);
                        // finalList[i].add = ("name",user.name);
                        // finalList[i].add = ("profilepic",user.profilepic);
                        // finalList[i].add = ("status",CODE);
                    }
                });

            }

        }

    });

});
```

Now, what is happening is that my array is returned null but data is inserted in **finalList** array also. Here is the console output:

```
[]
888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
[ { userId: '5485ae1159a751697e000003',
    name: 'aaaa',
    profilepic: 'https://graph.facebook.com/986962491123456/picture?type=large',
    status: 0 } ]
------------------------------------------
[ { userId: '5485ae1159a751697e000003',
    name: 'aaaa',
    profilepic: 'https://graph.facebook.com/123456781319929/picture?type=large',
    status: 0 },
  { userId: '5485ae1159a751697g7654003',
    name: 'ssss',
    profilepic: 'link',
    status: 0 } ]
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You don't do things synchronously in node. Why would you want to do it synchronously and block everything ? Use promises or callbacks to make it so you answer when all the asynchronous tasks you launch are finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this library - https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries. The method is `eachSeries`

Your code would look like this:

```
    var async = require('async');

    router.route('/user/:_id/host/:_id/joineeList').get(function (req, res) {
        var finalList = [];
        Host.findOne({
            _id: req.params._id
        }, function (err, host) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                var count = host.joinees.length;
                var limits = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    limits.push(i);
                }

                async.eachSeries(limits, function (i, callback) {
                    console.log(host.joinees[i].userid);
                    var ID = host.joinees[i].userid;
                    var CODE = host.joinees[i].status_code;
                    User.findOne({
                        _id: host.joinees[i].userid
                    }, function (err1, user) {
                        if (err1) {
                            console.log(err1);
                        } else {
                            finalList.push({
                                "userId": ID,
                                "name": user.name,
                                "profilepic": user.profilepic,
                                "status": CODE
                            });
                            callback();
                        }
                    });

                }, function() {
                    console.log(finalList);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Let me know if it helped

Comment: Thanks for the help! It is showing an error when I tried with your code. The Error is "ReferenceError: startAt is not defined"

Comment: @KanishkaSen Oops. It should be `i` instead of `startAt`. I've updated my answer - try now

Comment: I have another doubt. Could you please have a look at it. Here is the link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433032/modify-sub-documents-after-matching-parent-document-and-sub-document

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the parallel method of the async library (or maybe map) check it out https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Vitaliy Zurian. I have used the following code, by using counter in the for loop

```
 router.route('/user/:_id/host/:_id/joineeList').get(function (req, res) {
            var finalList = [];
            Host.findOne({
                _id: req.params._id
            }, function (err, host) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                    var count = host.joinees.length;
                    var limits = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        limits.push(i);
                    }
                async.eachSeries(limits, function (i, callback) {
                    console.log(host.joinees[i].userid);
                    var ID = host.joinees[i].userid;
                    var CODE = host.joinees[i].status_code;
                    User.findOne({
                        _id: host.joinees[i].userid
                    }, function (err1, user) {
                        if (err1) {
                            console.log(err1);
                        } else {
                            finalList.push({
                                "userId": ID,
                                "name": user.name,
                                "profilepic": user.profilepic,
                                "status": CODE
                            });
                            callback();
                        }
                    });

                }, function() {
                    console.log(finalList);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```